# Maven. Profile. Properties and System.getProperty()

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I want to use different maven profiles to set different parameters for tests needs. Parameter is a URL. Tests are on Groovy. I'm trying this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <useUrl>http://url</useUrl>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>another</id>
        <properties>
            <useUrl>http://url2</useUrl>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And groovy code:  `baseUrl = System.getProperty("useUrl")`

`System.getProperty("useUrl")` always returns 'null'.

But if I make configuration in surefire plugin like this:

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <baseUrl>${useUrl}</baseUrl>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

Code `System.getProperty("useUrl")` will return exactly what I expected - value from  active profile (`http://url` or `http://url2`).

System information:
Maven 3.2.5
Windows 8.1
Intellij IDEA 14.0.2

Could someone explain why profile properties don't work? Or what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Maven properties are not system properties.**

If you need to read/use system properties, you have to explicitly define it in a proper maven plugin, e.g.:

- `maven-surefire` plugin for unit tests
- `maven-jetty-plugin` for Jetty servlet container
- `exec-maven-plugin` for running your application using maven
- `properties-maven-plugin` for general usage